# What can be concluded about an operator's eigenvalue if its quadratic form takes on a negative value?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=(H,\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{L}:D(\mathcal{L}) \subset H \times H \longrightarrow H \times H$ a linear operator. Consider his quadratic form  $\mathcal{Q}$ associated to $\mathcal{L}$ given by
$$\mathcal{Q}(f,g)=\langle\mathcal{L}(f,g),(f,g)\rangle,\;\forall \; f,g \in D(\mathcal{L}).$$

If there exists $(f,g) \in D(\mathcal{L})$ such that $\mathcal{Q}(f,g)<0$. Can I conclude that $\mathcal {L} $ takes on a negative eigenvalue? This is in general true?

Comment: I think you need symmetry, that’s the hypothesis that connect the linear and the bilinear context

Comment: In this case, so $\mathcal{L}$ have a negative eigenvalue?

Comment: $\mathcal L$ does not need to have any eigenvalues, no matter what values quadratic form takes on.